# Operations Research Inventory Theory - No Shortages

Tags: derivatives

Inventory Theory - No Shortages Allowed - Deterministic Model

Book: "Introduction to Operations Research" 6th Ed. Hillier & Lieberman

Section 17.3 (Pg 762)

[Page One of Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6hDP.png)

[Page Two of Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYWJS.png)

On page two how are they solving for $Q*$.  When I take first and second derivative I get:

$$f^\prime(Q) = \frac{2ak}{x^3}$$

$$f^{\prime\prime}(Q) = -\frac{6ak}{x^4}$$

How is $Q* = \left(\frac{2ak}{h}\right)^{1/2}$?

Am I using the hint of $f^\prime$ is equal to zero incorrectly?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: your $f'$ is actually $f''$ In the example, you're given $f' = \frac{-aK}{Q^2} + \frac{h}{2}$ just set $f'$ to $0$ you can plug in the optimal policy $Q*$ to get the optimal inventory value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure what you're asking here but on page 1, they show:
$$
T = \frac{aK}{Q}+ac+\frac{hQ}{2}
$$
So
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}T}{\mathrm{d}Q} = aK\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}Q}Q^{-1} + \frac{h}{2}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}Q}Q = -aKQ^{-2} + \frac{h}{2}
$$
You now set this to zero:
$$\begin{aligned}
-\frac{aK}{Q^{2}} + \frac{h}{2} &= 0 
\\ \frac{aK}{Q^{2}} &= \frac{h}{2} 
\\ 2aK &= hQ^{2}
\\ Q &= \sqrt{\frac{2aK}{h}}
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Thank you for some reason I missed the Q in h/2. Thanks again.